# Prove that the following is not true or true.

Tags: number-theory

Prove that the following is not true or true. If $x,y,z \geq 1$ and they are all integers then $z^2=9xy+6y+6x+3$. If true, find $x,y,z$. If false, prove it.

I first tried some values but the fact that I am being asked to prove it if it is false, then I guess the above is false.

I tried some values like

$x=1,y=1$ then $z^2=24$ but that violates $z$ being an integer.

So if the above is false, how would i proceed in proving it.

EDIT: Sorry for all the confusion but I'm not trying to approach this problem by counterexamples. I want to know why does the equation $z^2=9xy+6y+6x+3$ not work? Why wont the left hand side ever provide a solution on the right hand side

Comment: How could that ever be generally true? Pick any $x$ and $y$ then there can never be more than one positive integer $z$ satisfying the equation, so any other choice of $z$ violates the condition. You should not formulate the second sentence as an "if...then" but as a statement of two facts, and then ask if such $x,y,z$ exist.

Comment: And If it is flase, then one should *disprove* the statement in spite of proving.

Comment: So @Maurico are you looking to find solutions regardless of the validity of the statement?

Comment: Do you mean to ask "find integers $x,y,z$ all $\ge 1$ such that [equation] holds"?

Comment: At a guess the intended question is "are there integers $x,y,z≥1$ which make the equation true?".  As you point out, there are plenty of such triples that make it false.

Comment: Taking $(x,y)=(5,8)$ gives the solution $z=21$.  (just a computer search).

Comment: I tried to sum up the discussion here in my answer. Hopefully it clears things up.

Comment: Sample: x=1,y=21,z=18..... If x=1 then $z^2=15y+9$ Let $y=3b$. Then $z^2=9(5b^2+1)$. There are infinitely many $b$ for which $5b^2+1$ is a square.

Answer (score 3):

So, there are two possible questions here:

$1)$ As stated, your question states, prove or disprove that $\forall x,y,z\in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1}$ 
$$ z^2=9xy+6y+6x+3.$$
Here is the counterexample: consider $x=y=z=1$. This implies
$$ 1=24.$$
This is blatantly false, and so this can not hold for all $x,y,z,\in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1}$.

$2)$ The alternative question states, prove or disprove that $\exists x,y,z\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge1}$ such that 
$$z^2=9xy+6y+6x+3. $$
Through software, or some sort of exhaustive calculation, we can see that $x=5,y=8\implies z=21$, a solution to the equation. So there exists such a $3-$tuple in $\mathbb{Z}_{\ge1}$ which solves the equation.

Comment: As does $(1, 9)$.

Comment: For a not-completely-brute-force approach: the RHS is divisible by 3, which is prime, so $z$ is divisible by 3. $z^2$ can't be $9$, it's too small for the RHS. Consider $z = 6$, then $9xy \leq 36 - 3 - 12 = 21$, we only have to check $(1,2)$ which doesn't work. Consider $z = 9$, so $9xy \leq 66$, $xy \leq 6$, at which point there are more cases to check than I'd bother with by hand before reaching for a computer, and I've run out of clever ideas...

Answer (score 2):

If you reformulate your statement as (which I guess is what the question is asking)

There doesn't exist integers $x,y,z≥1$ that satisfies $z^2=9xy+6y+6x+3$

Then the statement is still false. An counterexample would be $(x,y,z)=(1,9,12)$.

(It's easy to see $3|z$, and you can rewrite the equation as $z^2+1=(3x+2)(3y+2)$, so we just need to find a number of the form $(3m)^2+1$ that can be factored into two $3n+2$ type numbers. Trying out the first few possibilities gives $12^2+1=145=5\times29$.)

Comment: How is that a *counter*example?

Comment: From my understanding, a counterexample is an example that disproves a statement.

Comment: And how does this example *dis*prove the statement? Particularly since it's an "exists" claim, not an "all" claim?

Comment: OK my fault. For some reason I thought it's saying a solution doesn't exist.

Comment: @Niko: well, the questioner claimed no solution exists, and that indeed is what you've provided a counter-example to. So I think you're good :-)

Answer (score 1):

If it is not true then there exists a counterexample. You just found one. You're done.

Comment: I think there is a real mathematical problem hidden behind the confused grammar.

Comment: Please elaborate

Comment: I'm pretty sure he's looking for solutions to the equation, if any exist at all. I read it the same way, initially. I.e. show $\exists x,y,z\in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge1}$ satisfying the equation, or show no such tuple exists.

Comment: sorry for the grammar, im looking for more of a proof.

Comment: The way the statement reads right now is 
$$x,y,z\in \mathbb{Z_{\ge1}}\implies z^2=9xy+6x+6y+3.$$
You already have a counterexample to this statement. Do you mean to prove or disprove the existence of a solution set instead?

Comment: @Antonios I think that's it.

Comment: Why does the equation $z^2=9xy+6y+6x+3$ not work?

Comment: It's not the equation itself, its that your statement (as written) claims that all  integer $x,y,z \ge 1$ satisfy that equation, which is obviously false.

Comment: We like the equation, we are just confused about the non-existing problem that you formulated around it instead of simply asking whether the equation has any integer solutions greater than 0.

Comment: @Maurico it does not work for every case of $x, y, z$ that you specified, as you found an immediate counterexample. However it can work for certain values of $x, y, z$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution: $x=5,$ $y=8,$ $z=21.$

First note that $z$ must be a multiple of 3 and put $z=3k.$ Then note that $x$ and $y$ must be congruent to 2 modulo 3 and write $x=3l-1,$ $y=3m-1.$ Now the equation simplifies to

$$k^2=9lm-l-m.$$

Just try a few values of $l$ and $m$; the first ones that work are 2 and 3.

Comment: how would you know $x$ and $y$ is 2 mod 3 if you did not have a solution in front of you?

Comment: like someone said another solution is (1,9,12) but 1 mod 3 is 1 and not 2, and 9 mod 3 is 0 not 2

Answer (score -1):

You haven't quite understood the question.

z^2 is defined as the result got by adding together 9xy + 6y + 6x +3

you're being asked whether 9xy + 6y + 6x + 3 can be a perfect square,
when x and y are both positive integers.

Many integers are not squares; they want you to show 9xy + 6y  + 6x + 3 can be a square, presumably for just one set of values, though this seems unclear.

One approach might be to try to find x and y so that 3xy + 2y + 2x +1 is 3 x a square, such as 3, 12, 27, 48... maybe by factorising.

(x + 1)(y+1) = xy + y + x +1 umm..

or let's try x=y, so we get 9X^2 + 12x + 3 = 3(3x+1)(x+1).
Then say x+1 = 3M to allow for the 3
= 3(3M)(3x + 1)  to get a square, M (3x+1) must be square (where M=(x+1)/3)
so M( 3 (3M -1) + 1) has to be a square.
so M(9M -2) has to be square. So ... ummm...
Anyway, give it a go....